# React-router-redux error when creating store with middleware

Tags: reactjs, react-router, store, react-redux, history

I'm new to react-redux and trying to follow a tutorial that is a bit old, so when i try running this code i get error:

Uncaught Error: Expected the routing state to be available either as `state.routing` or as the custom expression you can specify as `selectLocationState` in the `syncHistoryWithStore()` options. Ensure you have added the `routerReducer` to your store's reducers via `combineReducers` or whatever method you use to isolate your reducers.

Any tips? :)

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import App from './containers/App'
import rootReducer from './reducers/reducers'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import api from './middleware/api'

let createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, api)(createStore)

let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer)

let history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

let rootElement = document.getElementById('root')

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path='/' component={App} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
)
```

my reducers.js looks like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import Auth from './auth'
import Quotes from './quotes'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: Auth,
    quotes: Quotes
})

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: Can you include your `./reducers/reducers` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You must add the routerReducer() for syncing to work in react-router-redux.**

This reducer function stores location updates from history. If you
use combineReducers, it should be nested under the routing key.

Include the following in your combine reducers.

```
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

export const reducers = combineReducers({
  ...  // other reducers
  routing: routerReducer
});
```

So your reducers file looks like:

```
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import Auth from './auth'
import Quotes from './quotes'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: Auth,
    quotes: Quotes,
    routing: routerReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: yes that's correct thanks! I still had the earlier suggestion "compose" in so it threw errors but now it works with this :)